# Pages keeps reloading on submit button

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm making a chat up using sioket.io. For some reason, when I hit the submit button, my page reloads.
I've used return false, I'm not rendering my post route either.
When I send I message, I want the message to pop up on the same page without reloading the page.

html:

```
<body>
    <form id="mario-chat">
        <div id="chat-window">
            <div id="output"></div>
        </div>
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Handle"/>
        <input id="comments" type="text" placeholder="Message"/>
        <button id="send">Send</button>
    </form>

    <script src="/javascript/superhero-movies.js"></script>
    <script src="/reload/reload.js"></script>

</body>
```

superhero-movies.js:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5500");

var comments = document.getElementById('comments');
var handle = document.getElementById('username');
var btn = document.getElementById('send');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    socket.emit('chat', {
        comments: comments.value,
        username: username.value

    });
    return false;

});


socket.on('chat', function(data) {

    output.innerHTML += '<P><strong>' + data.username + ': </strong>' + data.comments + '</p>';
})
```

index.js:

```
router.post("/superhero-movies", function(req, res) {
    const { comments } = req.body;
    const user = req.user;

    const sqlDatabase = require('../db.js');
    sqlDatabase.connect(function(err) {
        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log('socket connect successful');

            socket.on('chat', function(data) {
                io.sockets.emit('chat', data)
            })
        })
    })

    sqlDatabase.query("INSERT INTO comments (user_id, comments) VALUES (?, ?)", [user, comments], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(results);

    })

    router.get("/superhero-movies", authenticationMiddleware(), function(request, results, err) {
        results.render('superhero-movies');
    });
})
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is  <script src="/reload/reload.js"></script> ?

Comment: That''s not where the problem is. reload.js to reload pages instantly on save while running nodemon.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `form` tag. It's not necessary for making a chat using socket or ajax request.

Or without remove `form` tag, you can add `type` for your button. Without `type` defined, button will act as a submit button. And submit button will reload the page when it's clicked.

```
 <button type="button" id="send">Send</button>
```